# Why does changing the label mess up my plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have recently been playing around with various plot types using fictitious data to get my head around how I could display various pieces of information. One plot type that is gaining popularity is the so called individual differences dot plot which shows the change in each subjects score pre-post. The plot is fairly easy to produce, but my issue is that when I go to change the labels using either the `labs` or `xlab` `ylab` functions in `ggplot`, the plot itself becomes messed up. Below I have attached the fictitious data, the code used and the results.

**Data**

```
df<- data.frame(Participant<- c(rep(1:10,2)), Score<- c(rnorm(20,100,5)), Session<- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,                                                                                      2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))
colnames(df) <- c("Participant", "Score", "Session")
```

**Code for plot**

```
p<- ggplot(df, aes(x=df$Session, y=df$Score, colour=df$Participant))+ geom_point()+
  geom_line(group=df$Participant)+ 
  theme_classic()
```

**Plot**
[Individual difference plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvsY2.png)

My dilemma is that anytime I try to change the label names, the plot messes up as per below.

**Problem**

```
p + xlab("Session") + ylab("Score")
```

[Plot after relabelling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65IMQ.png)

The same thing happens if I try the `labs` function i.e, `p + labs(x= "Session", y= "Score")`. You can see that the labels themselves do actually change, but for some reason this messes up the actual plot. Does any have any ideas as to what could be going wrong here?

Comment: You do not need to use the `$` convention within ggplot. instead, use the column name itself: `ggplot(df, aes(x = Session, y = Score, colour = Participant))`. `group` within `geom_line` should be an `aes` as well

Comment: Yeah I am aware that the ```$``` convention is not needed within ggplot, but it's a bad habit I have picked up for when I have worked with larger datasets when the col names can be hard to remember. Usually I use the ```$``` just to bring up the list of col names and then delete it- forgot to here! 

Defining  ```group``` as an ```aes``` has worked a treat! So thank you for your time and help; greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you even need the group argument? Colour should be handling the grouping

Comment: @SmokeyShakers often I do need both `group=` and `colour=` in aesthetics to get it all correct. I can't reproduce it with this example, but I don't think it hurts, and often for me `color=` is not enough.

Comment: FYI, `data.frame(Participant <- 1:3)` is an anti-pattern in R. The `<-` assignment does not work as an argument-naming convention. In this case, it is literally creating a vector named `Participant` in the calling environment (and the other two vectors, too), and then due to R's chaining, the value assigned to `Participant` is then passed as the first value, *without its name* (e.g., this is why `a <- b <- d <- 55` works, because `d <- 55` returns 55, which is then assigned to `b`, etc). Unless you really need local vectors, change your inside `<-` to `=` (and drop `colnames`).

Comment: @r2evans I had a lot of difficulty reproducing the issue too. I could only reproduce if the grouping variable is a factor and it is set with `group = ` outside of `aes()`. I deduced the `Session` variable is actually a factor because of the breaks of the x-asis in the figure (and also the discrete scale of the color variable).

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the additional info there! I'm a R newbie, and by newbie I really do mean newbie. Great to be aware of these niches in the syntax!

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Yeah it seems that the group argument needed to be present, but this could be related to what r2Evans mentioned.

Comment: @IanCampbell You are correct. Apologies, I seem to not have included the code there for that- that's my bad- well deduced from the colour scheme and axis though!

Comment: For future questions, Cheddar_Thought, it appears that the data you provided here differs from your real data by the presence of `factor`s. Your question is a solid question in most regards: it has clear sample data, code attempted, and sample image, so +1 there. However, those new to R don't always recognize that the output on the R console of a frame that contains `factor`s does nothing to tell you that the data is not integer or string or numeric, which is part of the problem. An alternative would have been to provide `dput(head(x))`, since `dput` is unambiguous and shows the true nature.

Comment: @r2evans I'm still get used to both R and this platform RE making this reproducible, so please accept apologies there. Thank you again for such a comprehensive response and for your time in explaining these concepts. I will use ```dput(head(x))``` in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: No apologies! Perhaps [you're one of today's luck 10,000](https://xkcd.com/1053/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be the grouping is undone when the label functions are called. Instead, issue the grouping as an aesthetic mapping:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot)

df %>% mutate(across(c(Session,Participant),factor)) -> df

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Session, y=Score, colour=Participant))+ geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(group=Participant))+ 
  theme_classic() 

p + xlab("Session") + ylab("Score")
```

[image]

I suspect this is probably a bug.